# Matlab, Hide edittext and static text with radiobutton in GUI

Tags: matlab, radio-button, matlab-guide

here my listing to hide the static text and edit text in gui, but it not work

```
function uipanel1_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)   
    switch get(eventdata.NewValue,'Tag')
        case radiobutton1
            set(handles.text5, 'Visible', 'On');
            set(handles.edit4, 'Visible', 'On');
        case radiobutton2
            set(handles.text5, 'Visible', 'Off');
            set(handles.edit4, 'Visible', 'Off');
        case radiobutton3
            set(handles.text5, 'Visible', 'Off');
            set(handles.edit4, 'Visible', 'Off');
    end
```

tell me what mistake of my listing

Comment: Check [here](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/add-code-for-components-in-callbacks.html?searchHighlight=eventdata.newvalue#f10-1001546) if you just forgot to use strings in the switch statement. I.e. `case 'radiobutton1'`

Answer (score -1):

```
radiobutton(tag)=get(hObject,'Value');
if radiobutton(tag)
    set(handles.edittext,'Enable','off')
    set(handles.statictext,'Enable','off')
else
    set(handles.edittext,'Enable','on')
    set(handles.statictext,'Enable','on')
end
guidata(hObject,handles);
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to contribute an answer! Please explain your modification and why your solution should work where the original version failed - this way your post will have a higher chance to be useful to additional people in the future.

Comment: and about the modification just put the name that u gonna give it to the tag of radiobutton 
put this code in callback of radiobutton and if you want to liberate that space put this code :
set(handles.editTDma,'String','');
in the first IF 
and i hope its answered your question :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.